# How to add Plugin in .vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-you-complete-me

I am a new user of vim and want to add a plugin SuperTab for autocompletion. I searched for the plugin from vimawesome and it says

Place this in your .vimrc:

`Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'`

I've created a .vimrc file in my home directory but I don't know which commands to use before and after adding `Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'`

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on your plugin manager. There is handful list of them

- [minpac](https://github.com/k-takata/minpac)
- [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)
- [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) (I believe that this is the one in your description)
- [Dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim)

Alternatively you can install it manually either using “old fashioned way” (aka copy content of all directories into respective directories in `.vim`) or you can use built in package loader `:h pack-add`.